# Datetimepicker wont load when required libraries are loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I've been at this for HOURS now.

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Heres my code:

[image]

This will not load what so ever, I get errors like this:

[image]

And as you can see I have loaded all of the requirements at the top of the page.
[image]

I cant figure out this error, Anyone who will help it will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please don't edit your post to "fixed thanks" and delete all the content. Your question maybe help to others, but not if you delete your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorten format of document ready is this.

```
 $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
```

This will do the trick..

Comment: Still nothing. Should this be before anything or after anything?

Comment: seems you missed some loading. click all external links and check whether they loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

seems your document is not ready when your firing it..

Comment: This didn't work, but I think you have some of it down because I am loading TONS of javascript on this page.

Comment: check js are loading properly